Creating a prison on the high-pressure ice of a deep oceanic planet

I have a superoceanic (H2O) planet ~9.1x Earth’s mass and ~2.1x Earth’s radius. It is a superoceanic planet, meaning the planet is 100% covered in a global ocean 100s of kilometres deep; so deep that at the bottom there is a layer of ice VI (pressure at the bottom = ~10,000 bars). The oceans look turquoise in colour because of ferrous-ferric hydroxy salts dissolved in the oceans. The planet is modelled on current estimated parameters of Kepler-22b.
The atmosphere of this world has a pressure of 10 bars and is mainly composed of Nitrogen and some Carbon Dioxide; quite like Archean Earth but more pressurised. The average temperature at the surface of the water is 30°C.
I want to have a large underwater high security prison for the worst galactic criminals possible on this world. It needs to be set at the very bottom of the ocean floor, on the ice VI layer.
What materials would I need to design this prison of, so that I could maintain the structural integrity within the exterior, and a habitable pressure within the interior of the prison structure? Are there any materials we know of that would make this prison facility believable?

I say real world does not have materials that retain rigidity at such pressure, so the answer should be "not plausible with science-based". If allowed to handwave, just invent neutronium (SMACX) and use it.

Pressure equilibrium vs material strength (frame challenge)
You do not need a material that is able to withstand the full pressure of kilometers worth of water above an underwater base.
All you need is the same pressure inside that is also coming from the outside - at least in terms of stability.
Meaning: You can resort to average/commonly known materials like aluminum, steel, titanium etc. - what you see fit. But you need to focus on how to get the pressure equilibrium inside it to work. There can be handwaving solutions. Maybe there can be real feasible solutions.
Dome structure
Structurally you would probably aim for a dome with a two hull concept like in a submarine. The dome helps distribute pressure around the structure. The outer hull has only the use of compensating the pressure to the outside water. The inner would be the habitable hull providing breathable air and suitable atmospheric conditions.
The outer shell would probably still need to be reinforced further (in terms of armor) to withstand impacts from large animals, comets, weapon fire, etc.
Onioned Dome
Maybe you can even consider an onion layered dome concept. The outermost layer has to be the strongest, so you have a layer within it that applies counter pressure in a way (close to a full equilibrium) that the material strength is totally sufficient to withstand the forces. This is continued inwards until you can use lighter material strengths to provide the hull for the atmospheric conditions to live in.
Further considerations
What's also needed is a concept how to enter and exit the dome e.g. by docking a submarine? Or teleportation?
Certainly there should also be a concept for energy harnessing deep underwater and how to clean the atmosphere and get rid of waste products.
Enhancing the security level
You can enhance the concept to have something like a "death star underwater". A spheric vessel able to submerge to the ground and also relocate to undisclosed positions, making it even harder for attempted escapes. Instead of someone from the outside "just" needs to dive there, it is now additionally hard to even detect where that prison vessel is anyways... needle in a haystack effect for increased security.

This looks like a pretty good Frame Challenge. If you agree that's the case, it's useful to identify your answer as such so people look at it as a viable alternative given an identified problem rather than "not an answer."

@JBH thanks for the hint! I amended the title

The outer hull of duble-hulled submarines is not pressurized at all. It is basically either just a fairing, or a fairing combined with a certain amount of protection. (The fairing functionality is always the most important by far.) All the pressure of the water presses on the inner pressure hull. What the outer hull does is smooth the shape of the submarine so that it can move with greater ease through water; it also allows the inner pressure hull to have an irregular shape, for example by placing the reinforcing rings on the outside so that they don't occupy valuable space.

@AlexP true, I concur with you on the provided facts. I meant it as an analogy rather than a direct implementation of a submarine blueprint. ...maybe "inversed submarine hull concept" would be a better fit.

The question of how to get in (prisoners and staff) and out (staff only?) is a huge one.  If teleport exists then depending on exactly how it works it's pointless having a prison here, as the bad guys can just have their associates beam them out.  If teleport doesn't exist then it means engineering some major weak points into the structure and building a craft that can not only survive at that depth but also travel to/from the surface.

The extreme pressure could be used as part of the security - think of deep-sea divers and the things they must do to avoid getting the bends. You could have it be a sort of time-lock safe, where some undefeatable mechanism controls the interior pressure and/or nitrogen percent. If it only becomes safe to leave periodically, that's more work for the would-be escapee. Or it could even be security theater, where it's not as unsafe as the authority says it is.
